# TestNG not compatible with Eclipse 2019-03

Tags: eclipse, selenium

While trying to install TesgNG in Eclipse 2019-03 I got TestNG message as not compatible with Eclipse 2019-03.

[image: TestNG incompatible for Eclipse 2019-03]

Answer (score 2):

Try Install this Eclipse. 
I installed another version that you and I had the same problem. But in the Eclipse IDE for Java developers TestNG is available.
If u need more help, try this link too: https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/install-testng/

[Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E85hr.png)

Comment: This [link](http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release) should be used instead of [this](https://beust.com/eclipse) because of the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Only these versions of Eclipse are supported now
**Eclipse Versions:** Oxygen (4.7), Neon (4.6), Mars (4.5), Luna (4.4), Kepler (4.3), Juno (4.2, 3.8), Previous to Juno (<=4.1), Photon (4.8), 2018-09 (4.9)
**Java Version:** Java 1.7+ is required for running the TestNG for Eclipse plugin.
For any update follow this link: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/testng-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue without upgrading eclipse.

Go to: https://testng.org/doc/download.html

And try to download the plugin via the eclipse market. 
https://beust.com/eclipse

If this did not work try to remove the s> http://beust.com/eclipse

Comment: The "beust" links are not working anymore, but the "testNg" websites refences the correct link, which at the time of writing is: https://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/